# Horde and IMP in CentOS

Tags: centos, imp, horde

i'm having some problems with IMP and Horde,

i'm trying to log into the mail control panel but without success, this is what appears in shell

```
  user is not authorized for imp on line 259 of "usr/share/pear/Horde/Registry.php
```

I already google it and i found this : 
http://lists.horde.org/archives/horde/Week-of-Mon-20110711/041448.html

I followed what they are saying there, but the problems persists.

Any clue?!

Comment: probably need to adjust a file in the config, anyone having this problem may need to share their config files.